# How can I return to my raw data, after using BoxCox transformation?

Tags: time-series, arima, forecast

I am working  on  a forecasting project. After inspecting my time series, i decided to apply linear transformation by using R's forecast package's BoxCox function.

This function created an output variable which includes my transformed data. Afterwards I built my ARIMA model to forecast future values. However these forecasts are also in transformed scale. As BoxCox function makes calculations with precise lambda values, I am unable to specify functional form of my series (for example; i can't say if transformation is logaritmic or not).

So, I wonder if there is a function to transform series processed with BoxCox function to their orginal scale? Because I need to report forecasted values in orginal scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lambda` argument in the modelling function and don't transform your data yourself. All the modelling functions in the forecast package will do the BoxCox transformation for you, and back-transform the forecasts when you need them (including bias-adjustment if required). Here is a simple example:

```
library(forecast)
AirPassengers %>%
  auto.arima(lambda=0, biasadj=TRUE) %>%
  forecast() %>%
  autoplot()
```